# How to display messages in a chat application in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, web, chat

I am building a chat application in Django. But I am confused about how to show messages as soon as the person on the other side sends a message. At present, I have to reload the page to view the messages. I thought of refreshing the page automatically for 3-5 seconds. Is there any way to display messages as soon as the other person sends a message

Comment: read about ```websockets```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use websockets to obtain such type of applications . Web sockets maintain a link with your server and when ever there is a change in server the user gets notified automatically without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use websockets to accomplish this. The library to go is django channels (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and in their example they also build a small chat application.

Comment: Is there any other option other than channels and WebSockets. I have tried the above tutorial and I am struck at the docker part.

Comment: Docker is just used to run redis. You can also install redis locally and to connect it.